# Hide shipping address in paypal

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

I'm using paypal rest sdk for php and it works great. But how I remove shipping address? I found that there is key for that NOSHIPPING=1 but I don't know where to set it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using curl calls to utilize the rest api then add this `NOSHIPPING=1` along with the post data set for the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`